# Run/Test code in Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, code

Is there any feature in development for Stack Overflow to RUN/TEST code online? I see many questions are linked to some other online tools to run and test the submitted code/corrected code.

Like the below Online Tools:

> **Regular-Expressions** - http://gskinner.com/RegExr/
>
> **PHP code**
>
> - http://writecodeonline.com/php/
> - http://phpfiddle.org/                    -- Greate to use
> - http://ideone.com/                 -- Good to Share
>
> **CSS/HTML/Javascript/Jquery** - http://jsfiddle.net/
>
> **MySql/SQL** - http://sqlfiddle.com/
>
> **htaccess Test** - http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/
>
> **JSON Validator** - http://jsonlint.com/
>
> Here you Go!!
>
> **Many in one** - http://www.compileonline.com/

It will be very useful to explain what has be done. It will be nice if Stack Overflow has these features.

What do you say?

Comment: can I know why it is downvoted?

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for here. Code completion? Actual code compilation/execution in the browser? For every possible language?

Comment: People disagree that its a good or useful idea for this to be in Stack Overflow. It isn't. It is not something that helps write good questions or answers, is tangentially useful and is incredibly difficult to get right for **one** language, let alone **all** of them.

Comment: Why should Stack Overflow have these features? This isn't an IDE, it's a Q&A site. Besides, like you show here, all of these features exist elsewhere.

Comment: @Oded Well it wouldn't be very useful if it only worked for some of them now would it? Would _you_ want to be the one handling the support requests for "Why doesn't language X function Y behave the same as on my server?" I didn't think so. Better to just support all versions of everything.

Comment: I'd love to have our own JSFiddle sort of thing because the one that exists is constantly crashing, but it's just too much work to implement what has been implemented.

Comment: Thanks @TimPost for kind words..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I disagree with this. Stack Overflow is a Q&A site where you can ask and answers programming questions. It is not a compilation tool. If you want to show your code with compilation (e.g. to say code works fine), you can compile your code on particular tool. And add it's link on your post. But remember don't just add link in your post. You should add your code in your answer. Because when the particular site is down your post become invalid for that time. So we should not depend on external site.

Just for an example see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12870123/1369235) how can we post running code with external tools.

Comment: ...while also, of course, keeping the relevant code snippets in the question itself. =)

Comment: @J.Steen - Yeah just edited.

Comment: I think every one see the Stackoverflow the way it is now... why cant it have the feature.. to run and test the code.. so it will be best for the developer who ask question will run there code and show us the error! in this case many questions will not be closed by mentioning (what you have tried).

Comment: This is not a "debug my code for me" website, @Tom. The whole point is we shouldn't have to do all that work for people. They should include that information in their questions. They have a compiler right there in front of them already.

Comment: @TomPHP - How will this feature help our math, English Language, Christianity, Chess, Cooking and other non-programming sites?

Comment: @Oded do all thing development in SO is for all the sister website of SO? what cant some features been added with respect to the site goal.!

Comment: @CodyGray Yes I agree with your comments but it also means if some user added and shows code here.. by providing codes in tools.. it indirectly means they are also trying rite? sorry if my comment is confusing :(

Comment: @TomPHP - the goal of Stack Exchange is to have the best Question and Answer sites for many different topics. Stack Overflow is **one** of 100 such sites (at the moment) - the amount of effort you are asking for here would take multiple man years that can be spent improving the platform as a whole instead of for one site (where it isn't generally wanted or useful **anyway**)

Comment: @hims056 I am not just asking for an external tools I meant the tools can be of SO and they way we answer/ask question will be same but rather linking external tools we can have that in SO!

Comment: @Oded I think most of us didnt read my QA "Is there any feature in development" I am asking is it in Development? As for every one comments and answer I came to know that is is not in development. I understand you comments too. yup! it will be a big deal to do it. Just curious of having those in SO.

Comment: @TomPHP - But you have tagged it with [feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Comment: @hims056 hope now I removed it!

Comment: @TomPHP - Good now read my answer. :)

Comment: I was curious after seen http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/152859/sha-wiz-dow-ard sha profile as he can able to run the code for image change in other website and can link the result here in stackoverflow website.. so i just thought it will be a good feature to have some thing like this.!